# PHP display value outside foreach with array_push

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

**What I'm trying to achieve:**
Display `$currentSchoolPosition[0];` value e.g `3rd` within the `(Position Here)` message.

**Current Problem:**
When using the `$currentSchoolPosition[0];` string above the `foreach` the value displays `array();` if I move the string below the `foreach` the value e.g `3rd Position` displays.

How do I get the position value to display before the foreach ?

Thank you in advance!

**PHP**

```
<?php
  /* Current User ID */
  $currentUserID = get_current_user_id();
  /* Current User SchoolName */
  $currentSchoolName = get_the_author_meta( 'School-Name', $user_ID);
  /* Current User SchoolRegion */
  $currentSchoolRegion = get_the_author_meta( 'School-Region', $user_ID);
  /* Current User SchoolPosition Array - Empty */
  $currentSchoolPosition = array();
  /* Message */
  echo '<p>'.$currentSchoolRegion.' Leaderboard</p>';
  echo '<p>Your school <strong>'.$currentSchoolName.'</strong> is currently in (Position Here) position</p>';/* POSITION HERE */
  /* Get 'Subscriber' Users */
  $subscribers = get_users('role=subscriber');
  /* Subscriber School Array - Empty */
  $schoolArray = array();
  /* Counter - Start at '1' */
  $i = 1;
  /* Table */
  echo '<table class="table table-striped">';
  foreach ($subscribers as $subscriber) {
    $schoolName = $subscriber->get( 'School-Name' );
    $schoolRegion = $subscriber->get( 'School-Region' );
    /* If 'subscriber' region = current user region push school name(s) to 'schoolArray' */
    if($schoolRegion === $currentSchoolRegion){
      array_push($schoolArray, $schoolName);
    }
  }
  /* Count matching 'schoolArray' values */
  $subscriberValues = array_count_values($schoolArray);
  /* Reverse 'schoolArray' order - High to Low */
  arsort($subscriberValues);
  /* Reset Counter value - Start at '1' */
  $i = 1;
  foreach ($subscriberValues as $key => $value) {
    $counter = $i++;
    echo '<tr>';
    /* If 'counter' = '1' display 'Champion School' else display 'counter' value */
    if ($counter === 1) {
      echo '<th scope="row">Champion School</th>';
      echo '<td>'.$key.'</td>';
      echo '<td>'.$value.' Sign Ups</td>';
    } else {
      echo '<th scope="row">'.$counter.'</th>';
      echo '<td>'.$key.'</td>';
      echo '<td>'.$value.' Sign Ups</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
    /* Get current school position */
    if($key === $currentSchoolName){
      array_push($currentSchoolPosition, $counter);
    }
  }
  echo '</table>';
  echo $currentSchoolPosition[0].' Position'; /* POSITION VALUE HERE */
?>
```

**Anwser:** - Advice from Alan Machado!

```
<?php
  /* Current User ID */
  $currentUserID = get_current_user_id();
  /* Current User School Name */
  $currentSchoolName = get_the_author_meta('School-Name', $user_ID);
  /* Current User School Region */
  $currentSchoolRegion = get_the_author_meta('School-Region', $user_ID);
  /* Current School Position */
  $currentSchoolPosition = array();
  /* Get Subscribers */
  $subscribers = get_users('role=subscriber');
  /* Subscriber School Array */
  $schoolArray = array();
  /* Foreach Subscribers as Subscriber */
  foreach ($subscribers as $subscriber) {
    /* Subscriber School Name */
    $schoolName = $subscriber->get('School-Name');
    /* Subscriber School Region */
    $schoolRegion = $subscriber->get('School-Region');
    /* If Subscriber School Region matches Current User School Region PUSH School Name to Array */
    if ($schoolRegion === $currentSchoolRegion) {
      array_push($schoolArray, $schoolName);
    }
  }
  /* Reverse School Array Order - High to Low */
  arsort($subscriberValues);
  /* Count Matching Schoole Array Values */
  $subscriberValues = array_count_values($schoolArray);
  /* Foreach Get Current School Position */
  $i = 1;
  foreach ($subscriberValues as $key => $value) {
    $counter = $i++;
    if ($key === $currentSchoolName) {
      array_push($currentSchoolPosition, $counter);
    }
  }
  /* Header Message */
  echo '<p>'.$currentSchoolRegion.' Leaderboard</p><p>Your school <strong>'.$currentSchoolName.'</strong> is currently in '.ordinal($currentSchoolPosition[0]).' position</p>';
  /* School Leaderboard Table */
  echo '<table class="table table-striped">';
  $i = 1;
  foreach ($subscriberValues as $key => $value) {
    $counter = $i++;
    echo '<tr>';
    /* If 'counter' = '1' display 'Champion School' else display 'counter' value */
    if ($counter === 1) {
      echo '<th scope="row">Champion School</th><td>'.$key.'</td><td>'.$value.' Sign Ups</td>';
    } else {
      echo '<th scope="row">'.$counter.'</th><td>'.$key.'</td><td>'.$value.' Sign Ups</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
  }
  echo '</table>';
  /* Current School Position - Format */
  function ordinal($number){
    $ends = array('th','st','nd','rd','th','th','th','th','th','th');
    if ((($number % 100) >= 11) && (($number % 100) <= 13)) {
      return $number.'th';
    } else {
      return $number.$ends[$number % 10];
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: Do `print_r($currentSchoolPosition)` before and after your `foreach` and show us the output. It seems you have a multidimensional array.

Comment: @AlanMachado I have attached a screen shot with the Array Error! I hope this helps.

Comment: Before the `foreach`, your `$currentSchoolPosition` was just assigned an empty `array();` (line 9). After that, it received value through `array_push`, where then, after that, you access the index [0] of it, which have the value`3rd`.

Comment: Seems you have two choices: 1) Split your `foreach` statement in two: one assigns school position, other builds the table, separately. Or 2) do `echo '<p>Your school <strong>'.$currentSchoolName.'</strong> is currently in '.$currentSchoolPosition[0].' position</p>';` after your `foreach` (which doesn't seem to be a valid option for you, since you need the output up the table).

Comment: @AlanMachado Took your advice and this worked perfectly! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
  /* Current User ID */
  $currentUserID = get_current_user_id();
  /* Current User School Name */
  $currentSchoolName = get_the_author_meta('School-Name', $user_ID);
  /* Current User School Region */
  $currentSchoolRegion = get_the_author_meta('School-Region', $user_ID);
  /* Current School Position */
  $currentSchoolPosition = array();
  /* Get Subscribers */
  $subscribers = get_users('role=subscriber');
  /* Subscriber School Array */
  $schoolArray = array();
  /* Foreach Subscribers as Subscriber */
  foreach ($subscribers as $subscriber) {
    /* Subscriber School Name */
    $schoolName = $subscriber->get('School-Name');
    /* Subscriber School Region */
    $schoolRegion = $subscriber->get('School-Region');
    /* If Subscriber School Region matches Current User School Region PUSH School Name to Array */
    if ($schoolRegion === $currentSchoolRegion) {
      array_push($schoolArray, $schoolName);
    }
  }
  /* Reverse School Array Order - High to Low */
  arsort($subscriberValues);
  /* Count Matching Schoole Array Values */
  $subscriberValues = array_count_values($schoolArray);
  /* Foreach Get Current School Position */
  $i = 1;
  foreach ($subscriberValues as $key => $value) {
    $counter = $i++;
    if ($key === $currentSchoolName) {
      array_push($currentSchoolPosition, $counter);
    }
  }
  /* Header Message */
  echo '<p>'.$currentSchoolRegion.' Leaderboard</p><p>Your school <strong>'.$currentSchoolName.'</strong> is currently in '.ordinal($currentSchoolPosition[0]).' position</p>';
  /* School Leaderboard Table */
  echo '<table class="table table-striped">';
  $i = 1;
  foreach ($subscriberValues as $key => $value) {
    $counter = $i++;
    echo '<tr>';
    /* If 'counter' = '1' display 'Champion School' else display 'counter' value */
    if ($counter === 1) {
      echo '<th scope="row">Champion School</th><td>'.$key.'</td><td>'.$value.' Sign Ups</td>';
    } else {
      echo '<th scope="row">'.$counter.'</th><td>'.$key.'</td><td>'.$value.' Sign Ups</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
  }
  echo '</table>';
  /* Current School Position - Format */
  function ordinal($number){
    $ends = array('th','st','nd','rd','th','th','th','th','th','th');
    if ((($number % 100) >= 11) && (($number % 100) <= 13)) {
      return $number.'th';
    } else {
      return $number.$ends[$number % 10];
    }
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build the table first ( go through the foreach ), then echo it in the end after you have taken use of data created from the loop - something like this:

```
<?php

  /* Current User ID */
  $currentUserID = get_current_user_id();
  /* Current User SchoolName */
  $currentSchoolName = get_the_author_meta( 'School-Name', $user_ID );
  /* Current User SchoolRegion */
  $currentSchoolRegion = get_the_author_meta( 'School-Region', $user_ID );
  /* Current User SchoolPosition Array - Empty */
  $currentSchoolPosition = array();
  /* Get 'Subscriber' Users */
  $subscribers = get_users( 'role=subscriber' );
  /* Subscriber School Array - Empty */
  $schoolArray = array();
  /* Counter - Start at '1' */
  $i = 1;

  /* Table */
  $table = '<table class="table table-striped">';

  foreach ( $subscribers as $subscriber ) {
    $schoolName = $subscriber->get( 'School-Name' );
    $schoolRegion = $subscriber->get( 'School-Region' );
    /* If 'subscriber' region = current user region push school name(s) to 'schoolArray' */
    if ( $schoolRegion === $currentSchoolRegion ) {
      array_push( $schoolArray, $schoolName );
    }
  }
  /* Count matching 'schoolArray' values */
  $subscriberValues = array_count_values( $schoolArray );
  /* Reverse 'schoolArray' order - High to Low */
  arsort( $subscriberValues );
  /* Reset Counter value - Start at '1' */
  $i = 1;
  foreach ( $subscriberValues as $key => $value ) {
    $counter = $i++;
    $table .= '<tr>';
    /* If 'counter' = '1' display 'Champion School' else display 'counter' value */
    if ( $counter === 1 ) {
      $table .= '<th scope="row">Champion School</th>';
      $table .= '<td>' . $key . '</td>';
      $table .= '<td>' . $value . ' Sign Ups</td>';
    }
    else {
      $table .= '<th scope="row">' . $counter . '</th>';
      $table .= '<td>' . $key . '</td>';
      $table .= '<td>' . $value . ' Sign Ups</td>';
    }
    $table .= '</tr>';
    /* Get current school position */
    if ( $key === $currentSchoolName ) {
      array_push( $currentSchoolPosition, $counter );
    }
  }
  $table .= '</table>';

  /* Message */
  echo '<p>' . $currentSchoolRegion . ' Leaderboard</p>';
  echo '<p>Your school <strong>' . $currentSchoolName . '</strong> is currently in (Position Here) position</p>';
   /* POSITION HERE */
  echo $currentSchoolPosition[0] . ' Position';
   /* POSITION VALUE HERE */

  // print out the table
  echo $table;

?>
```